# Reading and replacing Integers in a string

Tags: java, string, integer

I have a string for example "x(10, 9, 8)" I want to read each integer from the string then using the integer as an array index retrieve a new integer from an array and replace it with this value.

All of the methods I've tried seem more suited to applying the same thing to all integers, or just retrieving the integers and then loosing track of them. Can anyone tell me the best way to do this please?

Comment: Is it always 3 numbers?

Comment: Can you give the code of what you tried? Why can't you parse the string into a temporary array to avoid losing values?

Comment: That's the case rob, no it can be 1 - 4 numbers

Comment: So in this case, if your array was [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0], you'd want to get a string "x(0,1,2)" as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you can "browse" through each number in your string, regardless of how they are separated, and replace them as required. For example, the code below prints `x(101, 99, 88)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 88, 99, 101};
    String s = "x(10, 9, 8)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuilder replace = new StringBuilder();
    int start = 0;
    while(m.find()) {
        //append the non-digit part first
        replace.append(s.substring(start, m.start()));
        start = m.end();
        //parse the number and append the number in the array at that index
        int index = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
        replace.append(array[index]);
    }
    //append the end of the string
    replace.append(s.substring(start, s.length()));

    System.out.println(replace);
}
```

Note: you should add some exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the numbers of your string using `Integer.parseInt()`, `String.split(",")`, and `String.indexOf()` (for the `(` and `)`. Create a `List` with them.

Iterate through this list and create a new List with the values from the array.

Iterate through the new List and create the response String.